# UIPasteboard is stubbornly persistent, no matter what I do

Tags: iphone, ios, uipasteboard

I am creating a application UIPasteboard with my app's identifier as a name (e.g. com.example.app.pboard) as suggested in the docs.

All the copying and pasting works, but the damn thing never goes away. I set its `persistent` property explicitly to NO every time I access it to copy something onto it, and I even call UIPasteboard's `+removePasteboardWithName:` every time my app starts.

But every time I look at it, the most recent thing I copied onto it is always there, despite app restarts.

What gives?

Comment: Did you get a solution? I just ran into the same problem. Removed a pasteboard from one app. Went to a different app and was still able to read the contents! (no it was not being re-created).

Answer (score 1):

No idea why what you are trying isn't working, here are two **guesses** and a possible solution:

- Removing the paste board may be expected to be executed on exit from the app, so it doesn't execute until the app is terminated or backgrounded?
- Calling remove and then asking for the items may be recreating it again in the same "place" so the items still remain.

You could perhaps solve this by setting the pasteboard's `items` to nil when leaving or entering the app.

Comment: Well, the first guess can't be right, since if i want to keep a pasteboard valid for the duration of a multitasking app, then there's never a valid time to remove it. That said, your solution worked-- on app start, I just get the pasteboard and nuke the `items`. Still can't explain it, but that does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set UIPasteboard to persistent. Accord to [Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipasteboard/1622096-ispersistent),

> `setPersistent:`
>   A Boolean value that indicates whether the pasteboard is persistent.
>   When a pasteboard is persistent, it continues to exist past app terminations and across system reboots. App pasteboards that are not persistent only last until the owning (creating) app quits. The system wide general pasteboard is persistent. Named, app-specific pasteboards are not persistent.

Update: For iOS 10, UIPasteboard set persistence automatically.

> Note
>   Starting in iOS 10, the system sets pasteboard persistence automatically. If you try to set the setPersistent: property on a pasteboard, Xcode issues a deprecation warning.
>   Instead of named persistent pasteboards, use shared containers, as described in the Overview section of this document.